# Java-WS XML serialization failed before JAXB unmarshaling occured

Tags: java, wcf, jaxb, xml-serialization, jax-ws

In my environment, I have client (java 6) call wcf (.Net 3.5) wcf service using JAX-WS and basicHttpBinding.

I have some invalid xml characters return from wcf service as string values.

I added custom JAXB  converter, like

```
<jaxb:javaType name="java.lang.String" 
        xmlType="xs:string"
        parseMethod="MyClass.parseStringToSafeXmlString" 
        printMethod="MyClassprintStringToSafeXmlString" />
```

MyClass have methods

```
 public static String parseStringToSafeXmlString(String value) {
      return stripNonValidXMLCharacters(value);
  }    


public static String printStringToSafeXmlString(String value) {
    return stripNonValidXMLCharacters(value);
}
```

Where `stripNonValidXMLCharacters` - some method to remove invalid chars (does not meter how it does).

But when i receive string with invalid xml chars, my code failed with exception **BEFORE `parseStringToSafeXmlString` was called** (for valid strings, method called and I stopped break point.

> Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at
>   [row,col]:[1,834] **Message: Character reference "&#x8" is an invalid
>   XML character.**  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:594)
>   ~[?:1.6.0_24]     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamReaderFilter.next(XMLStreamReaderFilter.java:81)
>   ~[?:1.6.0_24]     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:181)
>   ~[?:1.6.0_24]     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:349)
>   ~[?:1.6.0_24]     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.BridgeImpl.unmarshal(BridgeImpl.java:109)
>   ~[?:1.6.0_24]     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.Bridge.unmarshal(Bridge.java:222)
>   ~[?:1.6.0_24]     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.message.stream.StreamMessage.readPayloadAsJAXB(StreamMessage.java:249)
>   ~[?:1.6.0_24]     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.ResponseBuilder$Body.readResponse(ResponseBuilder.java:458)
>   ~[?:1.6.0_24]     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:110)
>   ~[?:1.6.0_24]

So I have 2 questions:

1. How can I fix it?
2. May I (and how) run my `stripNonValidXMLCharacters` or `any_other_remove_invalid_chars` method **before** failed (probably before xml serializer start works)?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Have you found a solution to your issue ?

Comment: Not exactly - it was long ago, may be things changes. But what I did I just sanitized invalid chars on the service size.

Comment: That's what I understood after all,but doesn't seem right not having an option to massage the data before truly consuming it; but the argument of invalid chars breaking the XML contract is also true. I think SOAP should be retired :)

Comment: @UCJava :) Gener ally - aggre